# Finding points satisfying inequalities

Tags: inequalities

I want to find a bunch of points $(x,y,z,u,v)$ s.t

$x^2-4u>0$ and $y^2-4v>0$ and $z^2-4uv>0$.
Here is what I did:

```
f[x_, y_, z_, u_, v_] := Max[x^2 - 4 u, y^2 - 4 v, z^2 - 4 u*v]
good[{x_, y_, z_, u_, v_}] := 
 If[f[x, y, z, u, v] < 0, "good", "notgood"]
tuples = Table[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}], 
   RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}], 
   RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 1, 10000000}];
grouped = GroupBy[tuples, good];
goodones = grouped["good"];
```

This is terrible I feel. There must be a better way, is there?

Edit: One helpful observation is that if $(x,y,z,u,v)$ is a solution then so is $(x+x_1,y+y_1,z+z_1,u,v)$ for where $x,x_1$ have the same sign. same for the other two.

Comment: Is 100 points enough? `FindInstance[{x^2-4u>0,y^2-4v>0,z^2-4u*v>0},{x,y,z,u,v},Reals,100]`

Comment: @Bill I forgot it can generate multiple solutions! Thank you this works!

Comment: If by "bunch" you mean "zillions", setting $u$ and $v$ will given you formulas for $x$, $y$, and $z$:   `Reduce[{x^2 - 4 u > 0 , y^2 - 4 v > 0 , z^2 - 4 u v > 0}, {x, y, z}] // FullSimplify`.